# Resolution of an inequality with floor

Tags: discrete-mathematics, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Given the inequality:
$$\left\lfloor \frac{k_1 - x}{k_2} \right\rfloor \le k_e $$
How can I transform it to find the smallest $x$ which satisfies the relation above? Thanks

Comment: Left hand side gets smaller the bigger $x$ gets so you probably mean smallest?

Comment: yes, sorry. I edited the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inequality is the same as
$$\frac{k_1-x}{k_2}<\lfloor k_e\rfloor+1$$

Comment: I could be more precise if you specify what kind of numbers $x$, $k_1$, $k_2$ and $k_e$ are.

Comment: $x$, $k_1$, $k_2$ are positive natural number, $k_e$ is real, thanks